# Ошибка компиляции библиотеки design в Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

После импорта и компиляции библиотеки design получаю ошибки вида:

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
>
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.

Компиляция других библиотек поддержки выполнятся без ошибок.

Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0). Compile with API 25.

Comment: Eclipse еще жив чтоль?

Comment: @iFr0z, вопрос не корректен - это универсальная платформа и на ней не только *когда-то писали под Андроид*. Но под Андроид писать на ней в 2019 году - то ещё извращение, конечно))).

Comment: Igor, кстати, чем вас Android Studio не устраивает? В Эклипсе собрать современное приложение - сложная задача (если вообще возможная). Какой версии `design` - в идеале все суппортные библиотеки в проекте должны быть одной версии и совпадать с target и compile API. P.S. Если захочется опубликовать приложение в гугло-маркет, то с API25 уже не пустят.